# java - how to make generic function that sorts alphabetically a collection

Tags: java, sorting, generics, comparator

i would like to create a utility method that can take in a list and sort it by its to string value. but i cant seem to figure out how to write the generic a param . here is what i have so far:

```
public class StringUtils {

    public static <T> void sortAscending(List<T> list) {
        Collections.sort(list.getClass(),
                new Comparator<T>() {
            public int compare(T f1, T f2) {
                return f1.toString().compareTo(f2.toString());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

the line "Collection.sort" complains at compile time that im not passing in the right thing.  How can i achieve this ?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Source code of Collections.sort() method is as follows:

```
@SuppressWarnings({"unchecked", "rawtypes"})
public static <T> void sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c) {
    list.sort(c);
}
```

It is clear that the method is expecting a List object and not a Class object.
So, your code should pass the list instead of list.getClass() leaving the code to be as follows:

```
    Collections.sort(list,
        new Comparator<T>()
        {
            public int compare(T f1, T f2)
            {
                return f1.toString().compareTo(f2.toString());
            }
        });
```